# Eloquent class not found when testing new models

Tags: phpunit, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm trying to test my eloquent models but my tests keep failing with "Class 'Eloquent' not found" errors.  If I add a route that uses my eloquent model and simply prints some of the information stored in the database, everything works fine.  It is only when trying to run phpunit that I get the issues with eloquent not being found.  My model is in app/models so it should be included in the composer classmap and I've done `composer dump-autoload`.  I'm sure I'm overlooking something really obvious but I can't pick it out.  Any idea what the issue is?

My test:

```
class GameTest extends TestCase {

    public function setUp(){
        $this->game = Game::find(1);
    }

    public function testGameInstance(){
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Game', $this->game);
    }
}
```

My model:

```
class Game extends Eloquent{

    protected $table = 'gm_game';
    protected $primaryKey = 'game_id';
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try adding parent::setUp() in your test's setUp function. This solved the issue for me.

Example:

```
class GameTest extends TestCase {

    public function setUp(){
       parent::SetUp();
       $this->game = Game::find(1);
    }

    public function testGameInstance(){
        $this->assertInstanceOf('Game', $this->game);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would have been as easy as looking through the docs again.
http://laravel.com/docs/testing